# Access iCloud Drive via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, dropbox, icloud

OS X 10.10 was just released, and one of the features I personally awaited the most was iCloud Drive. Unfortunately, I had to learn that it was not as accessible as Dropbox.

```
file ~/Dropbox
/Users/Ingwie/Dropbox/: directory
```

...but, iCloud Drive?

```
ls -1 Library/Mobile\ Documents/
./
../
.DS_Store
57T9237FN3~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/
5U8NS4GX82~com~dayoneapp~dayone/
(...)
```

Does anybody know, how to correctly access iCloud Drive via terminal? Or is this simply not possible and only presented nicely by the Finder App?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Step One, Setup a Link to the iCloud Drive Folder actual path:

First, create a **link** in your home directory to your iCloud drive:

```
cd ~
ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents iCloud
```

The lines above do the following:

```
// brings you to home directory
// creates link to said path as the name, 'iCloud'
```

Typing `cd ~/iCloud` in terminal will now deliver you to this directory.

### Step Two, Setup your Aliases in your Bash Profile:

Once, a link has been established, we need to setup an **alias**. Aliases are removed once we restart terminal, so we have to add an extra step where we edit a file called `.bash_profile` (or create one if we don't have one already).

Once done, we can simply type any binding and be delivered to our desired directory. In this example, we'll use `i` to take us right to our iCloud Documents folder.

We can create an alias to the iCloud Drive folder and save it in our bash profile as follows:

```
cd ~
ls -a
```

Look for a file called `.bash_profile`.

If you don't have `.bash_profile`, type:

touch .bash_profile

Enter your admin password and press enter.

Once you have found `.bash_profile`, or finished creating it, we must now open it and define our alias inside as follows. Type:

nano .bash_profile

You will again be prompted to enter you admin password. Enter it and press enter.

This will load up the nano editor. Press `esc` to be able to edit, and using the **keyboard**, arrow key down to the bottom. Type:

```
alias i="cd ~/iCloud/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents"
```

Press `Ctrl + O` to save, and then `enter`, then press `Ctrl + X` to exit.

Your alias is now saved. If we had not edited our `.bash_profile`, and just typed the alias in terminal, it would be erased when we restarted terminal. Adding this command into our bash profile will prevent this.

### Type your Alias in Terminal:

Now that you've saved your alias to your `.bash_profile`, we must finally execute our alias at least once (I tried not doing this and it didn't work), by re-typing our alias in the general terminal:

```
alias i="cd ~/iCloud/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents"
```

This will create the alias, and will now work. If you restart terminal, and run your alias command again, it should also still work.

### Results:

After this setup, we can simply type: `i` into the terminal, which will load our iCloud Drive\Documents directory.

Note: You can create any number of aliases to any folder, using any key binding you'd like, using the formula above. I just chose the Documents folder as this was the OP's question.

The above strategy was outlined in a tech blog article here: https://danielmiessler.com/blog/access-icloud-drive-terminal

Here's a tutorial on saving aliases to bash_profile:
http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-creating-aliases-for-commands-1305638

### How I Set Mine Up:

I setup an alias called `idev` where by typing that in terminal, delivers me to a `Development` folder I created on my iCloud drive at:

```
~/iCloud/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development
```

Note, the line above is still using the link setup initially in Step One.

My personal Alias I setup is as follows:

```
alias idev="cd ~/iCloud/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development"
```

Using a **link** and then an **alias** can allow us to access the iCloud docs folder easily. The most confusing part is editing the `.bash_profile` file, but overall just follow the steps and now any time you open terminal your aliases should work!

Comment: You should absolutely *not* be using `sudo` to edit your local user's shell-profile files.

Comment: I think that @ELLIOTTCABLE 's point is that though your answer may be well-intentioned, the idea of using root privileges to edit text files in your home directory suggests that (forgive me) you don't know what you're doing, and taking advice from you could be dangerous. I'm sorry to put it that way, but hopefully you can take this as at least somewhat constructive. To others: please disregard this answer, and take a look at the answer that just tells you to cd to the directory. Make a symlink with ln -s if you like, that's a good idea (I claim).

Answer (score 114):

You're correct in that the iCloud Drive directory is located within Mobile Documents. From your user's home directory, you can access iCloud Drive via terminal with:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
```

Comment: Awesome! Gonna symlink that into my home folder so I can spot it faster.

Comment: Has this moved? I don't even have a `Library/Mobile\ Documents/` directory.

Comment: @JosephHansen I'm not sure, on my system the Mobile Documents directory is still present as of OSX 10.10.1.

Comment: He has given a relative path here. Make sure you're in/at `~` before you copy pasta this into your terminal.

Comment: My mistake sorry, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also you can create an alias. 
'alias icloud="cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"'

Answer (score 6):

Matthew is right; IF you have iCloud Drive turned on in sysPrefs, the iCloud Drive folder is there, he was just listing it relative to your user account.

I'm not sure about the "com.apple.CloudDocs" though. The com~ files & plists for everything, including mobile apps, are NOT visible in Finder -only in Terminal.

As of 10.10.1 if you're looking for the absolute path to the all-encompassing directory, try:

```
 /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents
```

alternatively:

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the path to a file simply open the terminal (you can use the search tool), drag the file from finder in the terminal and it will provide you its path. 
This is however problematic with files in the iCloud Drive as apparently, the provided path does not work when trying to access it from other programs than the one it is registered with.

Answer (score 1):

I created an Automator App that run this terminal command:

```
open ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
```

You can download [here](http://equinsuocha.io/lab/iCloudDrive.zip). Just put it inside `Applications` and drag it to the dock.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot write comments.

Because of the ~ the path have to be in "" to open. I created a symlink to access it more easy.

```
sudo mkdir /mounts
sudo cd /mounts
sudo ln -s "/Users/fusca/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" iCloud
```